# Completeness and first order logic with Least fixed point operator (LFP)

Tags: first-order-logic, descriptive-complexity

Is there any result about the extension of first order logic with least fixed point operator, being complete (as logic in general on infinite structures too) or not? In other words does the Goedel completeness theorem of first order logic extent to such FO-LFP logic ?

Comment: If you can't get an answer here, I would try the TCS stack-exchange, it deals with research level questions, which I would possibly qualify this as. But there's a good chance someone here will know.

Comment: Thank you! I do put now the same question in TCS stack-exchange

Comment: Hmm, make sure you only have it on one site at a time, as there's a policy against crossposting. I'd reccomend you delete the post here and leave it on TCS, they'll tell you if it's not suitable for there. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Apparently, the respective question on TCS is this: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24906/completeness-of-the-extension-of-first-order-logic-with-least-fixed-point-order IMHO it does have some good answers.